# What statistical analysis should I use to compare shooting percentages in basketball?

Tags: proportion

If I want to compare shooting percentages (basketball) in two conditions, what type of statistical analysis would I use? If I enter data in columns

condition 1 makes
condition 1 attempts
condition 2 makes
condition 2 attempts

Is that a bad way to do it?

Should I assign a 1, 0 to make and miss and compare by groups?

Any advice?

I want to look at shooting percentages on lay-ups off of one foot vs lay-ups off of two feet in girls varsity basketball.

Answer (score 1):

If you'll have different groups of shooters trying the two methods, you could use a Chi-Square Test or a Test of Independent Proportions.  If the same group will be trying both methods, you'll want the Test of Dependent Proportions.  An intro statistics book, a google seach, or perhaps Wikipedia should give you the specific steps to take.

Answer (score 1):

$\chi^2$-test (Chi-Square) is a good way as @rolando2 suggests. I would just like to add that Khan Academy has a [LeBron basket question](http://www.khanacademy.org/new-and-noteworthy/v/lebron-asks-about-the-chances-of-making-10-free-throws) that you might enjoy. The statistics at Khan Academy is awesome, you can find the $\chi^2$-test explained [here](http://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics/v/chi-square-distribution-introduction) although you might want to start a little earlier in the [statistics videos](http://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics).

Comment: +1 for the linking $\chi^{2}$. This tutorial is awesome.